# add site labels to ggplot2 graph: Aesthetics must be either length 1 error

Tags: r

I know this error has been answered to death, but I can't find a solution that works for me. I've tried changing the fill parameter but still get the same error.

I am just trying to add site names to the graph. This is my code:

```
#Load packages
require(ggplot2)
require(ggmap)
require(maps)
require(mapproj)
require(mapdata)
require(rgeos)
require(maptools)
require(sp)
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
require(dismo)
require(ggsn)

##nova scotia 
base1 = get_map(location=c(-62.10,45.40,-61.10,46.30))

map1 = ggmap(base1)
map1
```

[image]

```
## site coordinates for NS

sites_NS <- read.table("EC_stick_sites_novascotia.txt", header = T, row.names = 1)
sites_NS
                       lat     long type ID
Pomquet Lake       45.6228 -61.8394   FW PO
Lake Ainslie       46.1323 -61.1778   FW LA
Black River        46.1576 -61.2751   FW BR
Antigonish Landing 45.6309 -61.9607    M AL
Porper Pond        45.4403 -61.3209    M PP


map1 + 
  geom_point(data = sites_NS, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_text(label = rownames(sites_NS))+
  labs(title = "Collection sites in Nova Scotia", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")
```

ERROR:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred
```

But there is 5 sites not 4! Confusing :(
With this code I can add points for each site:

```
sites_NS <- read.table("EC_stick_sites_novascotia.txt", header = T)
limts <- c(xmin =  .2 + min(map1$data$long),
           xmax = -.2 + max(map1$data$long),
           ymin =  .1 + min(map1$data$lat),
           ymax = -.1 + max(map1$data$lat)
)

map1 + 
  geom_point(data = sites_NS, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Collection sites in Nova Scotia", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") + 
  ggsn::scalebar(x.min = limts[1], x.max = limts[2], dist_unit = "km",st.size = rel(2.5),
                 y.min = limts[1],  y.max = limts[2], 
                 dist = 5, transform = TRUE, height = 0.01,
                 model = "WGS84", location = "topleft")
```

but I'd like to have the names on the graph (or in the legend) and colour-coded according to 'type' FW (freshwater) or M (marine). [image]

Edit:

```
map1 + 
  geom_point(data = sites_NS, aes(x = long, y = lat, shape = Habitat, color = Habitat), size = 4) +
  geom_text(data = sites_NS, aes(x = long, y = lat,label = ID), vjust = -0.5, size = 4) +
  labs(title = "Collection sites in Nova Scotia", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude" )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not sharing a dataset I will try to explain the problem with `mtcars`.

The problem you have is that the `geom_text` function in the following

```r
map1 + 
  geom_point(data = sites_NS, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_text(label = rownames(sites_NS))+
  labs(title = "Collection sites in Nova Scotia", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")
```

has two problems

1. It doesn't know here to place the text, because there aren't `aes(x, y)` for it.
2. It doesn't have an explicit `data=` so it looks for the aesthetics in the parent `ggplot()` call. But that one is `ggmap(base1)`, where `x` and `y` coords aren't defined.

Since neither the `data` nor the `x`, `y` coords aren't passed in the parent `ggplot()` call, you need to specify them in every `geom_*` call. Someting like the following

```r
d = head(mtcars)
ggplot() + # note i don't put any dataset or `aes()` here
  geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg), data = d) +
  geom_text(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, label = rownames(d)), data = d)+
  labs(title = "Collection sites in Nova Scotia", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")
```

But if we specify 'global' aesthetics, the code would look like

```r
ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg), data = d) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = rownames(d))+
  labs(title = "Collection sites in Nova Scotia", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas. I've edited the question above to incorporate your input. Looks much better. I've been trying to change the colour of the points such that the triangles are black and the circles blue, but haven't gotten it to work. The colours right now don't stand out. When I try to specify, It adds another legend or changes all the colours to just one rather than two.  The data is in the question under "sites_NS".